# How can subtract a character from csv using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to insert my CSV into my SQL Server database but just wondering how can I subtract the last three character from CSV GID column and then assigned it to my $CSVHold1 variable.

My CSV file look like this

```
GID       Source               Type   Message   Time
KLEMOE    http://google.com    Od      Hello     12/22/2022
EEINGJ    http://facebook.com    Od     hey      12/22/2022
```

Basically I'm trying to get only the first three character from GID and pass that value to my $CSVHold1 variable.

```
       $CSVImport = Import-CSV $Global:ErrorReport
        ForEach ($CSVLine1 in $CSVImport) {
            $CSVHold1 = $CSVLine1.GID | ForEach-Object { $_.$GID = $_.$GID.subString(0, $_.$GID.Length - 3); $_ }
            $CSVGID1 = $CSVLine1.GID 
            $CSVSource1 = $CSVLine1.Source
            $CSVTYPE1 = $CSVLine1.TYPE
            $CSVMessage1 = $CSVLine1.Message
            }
```

I'm trying to do like above but some reason I'm getting an error.

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
```

Comment: `$_.$GID` is null and `$_.$GID.subString(..)` will throw "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression." I think you just meant to do `$CSVHold1 = $CSVLine1.GID.SubString(0, $CSVLine1.GID.Length - 3)` tho your question is unclear

Comment: Hi Santiago. Yes I do get the error. I tried the solution that you gave me but some reason I'm still getting the same error. "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

Comment: I dont understand what you need so unless you update the question stating what you have and what you want I cannot help

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. Please check.

Comment: So, what is the point of overwriting your variables in every iteration? Is there more code in the loop we cannot see? Are you trying to recreate your csv with altered values in the `GID` column?

Comment: Hi @Theo , Yes there are more code in the forloop but basically I'm trying to insert altered values into my sql server database. In my db tables, there is Hold Column that's why I'm trying to get the first three character from GID and fill that in.

Comment: Be aware that the `SubString` method will fail if the length of `$CSVLine1.GID` is below 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original line 3 was/is not valid syntax as [Santiago](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) pointed out.

```
$CSVHold1 = $CSVLine1.GID | ForEach-Object { $_.$GID = $_.$GID.subString(0, $_.$GID.Length - 3); $_ }
```

You are calling `$_.$GID` but you're wanting `$_.GID`

You also don't need to pipe the object into a loop to achieve what it seems you are asking.

```
#!/usr/bin/env powershell

$csvimport = Import-Csv -Path $env:HOMEDRIVE\Powershell\TestCSVs\test1.csv

##$CSVImport = Import-CSV $Global:ErrorReport

ForEach ($CSVLine1 in $CSVImport) {
    $CSVHold1 = $CSVLine1.GID.SubString(0, $CSVLine1.GID.Length - 3)
    $CSVGID1 = $CSVLine1.GID 
    $CSVSource1 = $CSVLine1.Source
    $CSVTYPE1 = $CSVLine1.TYPE
    $CSVMessage1 = $CSVLine1.Message
    Write-Output -InputObject ('Changing {0} to {1}' -f $CSVLine1.gid, $CSVHold1)

}
```

Using your sample data, the above outputs:

```
C:> . 'C:\Powershell\Scripts\dchero.ps1'
Changing KLEMOE to KLE
Changing EEINGJ to EEI
```

Lastly, be aware that that the `SubString` method will fail if the length of `$CSVLine1.GID` is less than 3.